# For-loop through one object to build a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

**Question:** Using the JSON OBJECT outlined below I need to complete (fill in) the Code snippet example so that it looks like the second block of code. I am not sure how I would loop through the JSON OBJECT to build what is being pushed into the _etmc object. Please let me know if I left anything out that might be helpful to solve my question.

Code snippet example:

```
 _etmc.push(["trackCart", { “cart”: [
    {"item" : "INSERT_ITEM", "quantity":  "INSERT_QUANTITY" , "price" : "INSERT_PRICE" ,
            "unique_id" : "INSERT_UNIQUE_ID" }
   ]}]);
```

**Below is how the above code should look in the end:**

```
_etmc.push(["trackCart", { “cart”: [
    {"item" : "digitalData.cart.item[0].productInfo.productName", "quantity":  "digitalData.cart.item[0].quantity" , "price" : "digitalData.cart.item[0].price" ,
            "unique_id" : "digitalData.cart.item[0].productInfo.sku" } ,
    {"item" : "digitalData.cart.item[1].productInfo.productName", "quantity":  "digitalData.cart.item[1].quantity" , "price" : "digitalData.cart.item[1].price" ,
            "unique_id" : "digitalData.cart.item[1].productInfo.sku" } 
{"item" : "digitalData.cart.item[2].productInfo.productName", "quantity":  "digitalData.cart.item[2].quantity" , "price" : "digitalData.cart.item[2].price" ,
            "unique_id" : "digitalData.cart.item[2].productInfo.sku" }
{"item" : "digitalData.cart.item[3].productInfo.productName", "quantity":  "digitalData.cart.item[3].quantity" , "price" : "digitalData.cart.item[3].price" ,
            "unique_id" : "digitalData.cart.item[3].productInfo.sku" }
{"item" : "digitalData.cart.item[4].productInfo.productName", "quantity":  "digitalData.cart.item[4].quantity" , "price" : "digitalData.cart.item[4].price" ,
            "unique_id" : "digitalData.cart.item[4].productInfo.sku" }
   ]}]);
```

**this is my JavaScript object:**

```
  var digitalData = [
"cart":{
    "item":[
        {
        “productInfo":{"productID":"p1234”,”productName":"Bamboo Towel”,”sku":"320020454"},
        "category":{"primaryCategory":""},
        "quantity":"3",
        "price":"10.0",
        "discount":[]
        },

        {
        "productInfo":{"productID":"p2345”,”productName”:”Arm Chair“,”sku":"810047424"},
        "category":{"primaryCategory":""},
        "quantity":"1",
        "price":"10.0",
        "discount":[]
        },
        {
        "productInfo":{"productID":"p3456”,”productName”:”Bathroom Rug“,”sku":"330016238"},
        "category":{"primaryCategory":""},
        "quantity":"1",
        "price":"6.0",
        "discount":[]
        },
        {
        "productInfo":{"productID":"p4567”,”productName”:”Bedroom Full Set”,”sku":"810038458"},
        "category":{"primaryCategory":""},
        "quantity":"1",
        "price":"7.0",
        "discount":[]
        },
        {
        "productInfo":{"productID":"p5678”,”productName”:”Outdoor Table”,”sku":"330016874"},
        "category":{"primaryCategory":""},
        "quantity":"1",
        "price":"39.99",
        "discount":[]
        }
           ]
    }
]
```

This was one of my tries at populating _emtc with the info from the digitalData object:

```
_etmc.push(["trackCart", { “cart”: [  
    for ( var i = 0; i < digitalData.cart.item.length; i++) {
        var obj = digitalData.cart.item[i];
        console.log(obj);

        for ( var key in obj) {
            {"item" : "_satellite.getVar(obj + .productInfo.productName)", "quantity":  "_satellite.getVar(obj + .quantity)" , "price" : "_satellite.getVar(obj + .price)" , "unique_id" : "_satellite.getVar(obj + .productInfo.sku)" },  

        }
        ]}]); 
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want from `items`? It would be helpful to post the current data format (which you did) and an example of what the final form would look like

Comment: You can't have a `for` statement inside of an array...

Comment: @RobM. I am not sure what else I can show you the top snippet is what I am trying to create the second is my json object and the third is me trying to fill in the blanks of number one with data from the json object using paths so (obj + .productInfo.productName)  would be digitalData.cart.item[0].productInfo.productName If I missed something else just let me know.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan if I cant have it in my array maybe I build the elements of the array in the for loop save it in a variable and then add the rest of the original array elements kind of like building it in pieces and putting it back together?

Comment: It's just not valid JavaScript. I think your first step is to look at some tutorials on JavaScript; how it works, syntax, the basics. You're on the right track though.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan updated question by combining all of the communities edits and the new question I had opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a `for` loop inside an object or array literal. The loop should execute `push()` in its body.

And when you want to concatenate the value of a property with a string, you need to end the string first.

```
for (var i = 0; i < digitalData.cart.item.length; i++) {
    var obj = digitalData.cart.item[i];
    _etmc.trackCart.cart.push({
        item: "_satellite.getVar('" + obj.productInfo.productName + "')",
        quantity: "_satellite.getVar('" + obj.quantity + "')",
        price: "_satellite.getVar('" + obj.price + ")",
        unique_id: "_satellite.getVar('" + obj.productInfo.sku + "')"
    });
}
```

I'm not sure I understand what you're doing with `_satellite.getVar`, I suspect it's not needed at all, and the actual code should just be putting the values of the properties in the resulting object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < digitalData.cart.item.length; i++) {
    var obj = digitalData.cart.item[i];
    _etmc.trackCart.cart.push({
        item: obj.productInfo.productName,
        quantity: obj.quantity,
        price: obj.price,
        unique_id: obj.productInfo.sku
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example that make sense I guess I thought all of the elements being "pushed" into _etmc all had to happen at once and could not be pushed in one at a time now that the for-loop is around the push and not inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the map method of the Array prototype to iterate through the item property in your JSON response. This will give you a new array with just your items.

```
var items = jsonResponse.cart.items.map(function(item) {
    return item;
})
```

See [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for reference on MDN.